# Tkinter Canvas Dynamically Delete/Animate Object

Tags: python, tkinter

There are a few ways around this, but is there a way to run this code in a similar way?

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

...canvas stuff...

class thing():
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(...)
    def something(self):
        canvas.delete(self.id)
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(...)
        canvas.move(self.id, 10, 0)

t = thing()
while True:
    t.something()
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

The script above should animate a circle but it doesn't. (btw) I'm not looking for a way to fix this code.

Is there a way to dynamically create object names (to replace self.id dynamically)?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Can you explain more? What is it about self.id that you don't like?

Comment: the code above sort of won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a function that performs one frame of your animation. Then, use `after` to run that command on a schedule.

Here's a very basic example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

class thing():
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 20, 20, outline="red", fill="red")

    def animate(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 10, 10)
        self.canvas.after(100, self.animate)

t = thing(canvas)
t.animate()
root.mainloop()
```

Of course, you need to add additional code to be able to stop the animation, or to change it when the object encounters an edge or goes off screen, etc. This illustrates the general principle, however. Within `animate` you can add any additional logic that you want.